Which way to visit the pyramids of Giza from Sharm el-Sheikh is most feasable?
I plan on going on vacation in Sharm el-Sheikh and I would like to visit the pyramids.
I have researched the following options:

Rent car and drive myself (5.5h one direction according to google), 40€ car rental for one day
Bus - seems impossible with children, 7h in one direction, 24h trip
Plane (organized), 200€ per person or 150 if one direction by bus
Plane (40€ one way ticket to cairo, self organized), maybe another 40 for taxis

Which one of these makes the most sense? Are there any costs I have not accounted for?
Is it easy to drive in Egypt? I have an EU license.
If the google estimates are true, it may actually be best to drive, spend one night in a cheap hotel in Cairo for 18€ and try to also visit Luxor.

Do you only consider time against money or do you also include safety (road and war/terrorist).

To add onto @Willeke comment, many governments warn against travel (EG here, and here) on the western side of southern sinai  (the route you would need to take to Cairo), and basically state you should only do essential travel.  In these warnings, Sharm el-Sheikh is considered a bubble of safety.  And if you have to ask "is it easy to drive in Egypt?", then IMHO you are not prepared for such a trip.

Do not drive in Sinai.

@littleadv why not?

@Willeke I did not account for safety, is Egypt unsafe now?

@PeterM I ended up opting for Hurghada, glad to know it was the right call for other reasons also.

@user1721135 see the comment by Peter M, I have also heard warnings in other places, but I have never studied the risks.

This is both itinerary-planning and opinion, both off-topic here where we look to answer questions that have an answer. I voted to close.

@user1721135 because it's extremely dangerous. There is a lot of criminal activity happening there, and an Islamic insurrection backed by ISIS still going on. Westerns are not welcome.

It depends on many factors (and many of them are personal factors). So impossible to answer (this is a reference site, not a forum). In any case, also driving, it means 12 hours travel, and you want some time to visit. -- Personally: if you want to see Cairo and Pyramids, you need more days, so either you plan your flights to have one stop in Cairo, or if you stay two weeks in a resort, take few days off. -- Or probably better (but check price of flights): organize a long weekend just in cairo at a different period.

@GiacomoCatenazzi visiting the pyramids will suffice, I will skip Cairo. Google maps shows 5h drive, if true it could be done in a day (5h to pyramids, 5h there, 5h back).
